# Select an iTunes App ID: You'll need to provide an iTunes ID and URL to run this iOS 14 campaign. (#2490250)

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, ios14, adsmanager

I am getting an error in facebook business Ads manager.

While creating a campaign with "App promotion" as an option and turning IOS 14+ campaign on. I am getting an error saying: "Select an iTunes App ID: You'll need to provide an iTunes ID and URL to run this iOS 14 campaign. (#2490250)"

But I am unable to add the App id in Choose App input as it does not say anything.

Any Help appreciated